# Resource Files how to name them?

Tags: c#, .net, resource-files

I am playing around with resource files and have run into a problem.

I have a folder called Languages. When I make a resource file and say call it "R.resx" I can call this resource file up in my classes.

If I rename this file(or delete and make a new resource file) and call it  R.en.resx I **cannot** call this resource file up in my class anymore.

Does the first language need to be in R.resx where the rest would be R.language.resx?

Comment: When you rename the resource file, do you rename (or delete) the accompanying designer file and the classes that are generated?  Perhaps the old designer file is causing naming conflicts for your newer ones.

Comment: I just did the resource file not the designer. However I covered that base by deleting the entire resource file(so that would include the designer) and then added a new one called R.en.resx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Step 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx)

To create resource files for additional languages, copy the file in Solution Explorer or in Windows Explorer, and then rename it using one of the following patterns:

```
For global resource files:

name.language.resx

name.language-culture.resx

For local resource files:

pageOrControlName.extension.language.resx

pageOrControlName.extension.language-culture.resx
```

So yes, you are correct in your assumption that the base resource file would be the first language.

EDIT:

```
var temp = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.BaseName.Replace("YourNamespace.Properties.","");
```

You may have to also do this (to get rid of the language part after the name chunk):

```
 temp = temp.Replace(".thelanguagechunk","");
```

This code would get you the "name" chunk you are after by itself.

Comment: So that would be the fall back one?(if it can't find the a resource file that would best fit the user then it uses that one correct). So in a sense any English users that come to my site would always fall back to the default one(unless I started going into U.S English and all the other ones). This is sort of a side question but is it possible to get the name in the "Name" column in the resource file?

Comment: You would be correct that the base resource file would probably be best suited for the majority of your users and then additional ones would be made for users of smaller demographics. Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.BaseName gets you the name of the .resx file that is currently being used. Granted in has the namespace.properties appended to it, but you can easily extract what you need from there.